# How to suppress repeating values in a manner that takes into account previous conditional formatting? (Google Calendar-like scheduling blocks)

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm in the process of creating a [scheduling template](https://www.flickr.com/photos/123478898@N05/14096906534/).

I'm trying to figure out how I create a conditional formatting formula for suppressing repeating values that takes into account the conditional formatting (highlighting specific colours based on specific text) I've already implemented. Basically, I'm trying set up the schedule so that the first row of each text is visible, but that repeating rows below only show the highlight (i.e., values suppressed)--something akin to Google Calendar. I've used data validation to create a drop-down menu (of work activities) based on the following [list](https://www.flickr.com/photos/123478898@N05/13909825309/in/photostream/) (kept in a separate worksheet). Keep in mind that this is my first go at this sort of thing (I'm likely going to reduce the amount of colour).

Comment: The following formula works:

=AND(B2=B1,B2="Info Desk")

However, it leads to only the bottom row of consecutive repeated values being displayed (what I'm looking for is only the top row being displayed). I've played around with rule order, but have not had any luck.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As a seperate rule from your colouring rule, use

```
=A1=OFFSET(A1,-1,0)
```

and for the Format, use `Number` Format, `Custom`, `;;;`

Apply to a range starting at `A1`

Note: I use `OFFSET` so that the formating is not broken if you insert a row, as it would be with `=A2=A1`